# POST запросы в Android. Как?

Tags: java, android

Решил попробовать пописать под Android, соответственно появилось очень большое количество вопросов. Кому не трудно ответьте пожалуйста.
Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы приложение работало с неким API, общение с помощью `json`, но у меня не получается написать класс, как например на шарпе, в который я передаю адрес, параметры и выполняю `POST` запрос, например как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post.
Насколько я понял приложение на Android не может выполнить `POST` запрос из обычного метода, нужно использовать `AsyncTask<>` - тут я вообще ничего не понял, начиная от самого синтаксиса, а именно `doInBackground(String... params)` - `String...` это перечисления параметров при вызове метода типа `doInBackground(str1, str2, str3)` или как?
В общем **я не прошу написать за меня готовый код**, прошу помочь понять принцип как работать с `POST` запросами в Android, хотя бы один конкретный пример: отправка `POST (json)` и получение ответа так же в `json` и немного теории, пжлст)).

Comment: Любые запросы к внешнему миру делаются только в асинхронном блоке то есть `AsyncTask`, Касательно `doInBackground(String... params)`  где `String... params` это массив не объявленной величины, там как могу быть параметры так и нет, работать с `params` нужно как с массивом. Есть библиотеки, которые уже побеспокоились о много поточности и прочем другом за вас например [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: @Victor а что значат параметры в `AsyncTask<Param, Param, Param>` как я понял первое это тип входящего значения, второй тип промежуточного значения(???), третий это тип возвращаемого значения, верно? Что есть промежуточное значение?

Comment: Я думаю [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php) ответят лучше меня

Comment: @Victor спасибо, почитаю

Comment: Стоит ли писать про `Volley`?

Comment: прикольно, загуглил и наткнулся на свой же вопрос)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AsyncTask` лучше один раз попробовать, и потом забыть про них. То же самое касается и `HttpUrlConnection`. В настоящий момент основной библиотекой для взаимодействия с Rest сервером в Android считается [Retorofti](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). На официальном сайте есть примеры. Так же их не мало и на сторонних ресурсах, например [здесь](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client). Приведу лишь пример `POST` запроса.

Для этого нам потребуется класс-модель, в которую преобразуется полученный от сервера Json, класс-модель для тела запроса и интерфейс с методом аннотированным специальной анотацией.

Допустим сервер имеет метод, который добавляет почтовые адреса пользователю, и возвращает какую то информацию о статусе операции. В теле запроса сервер принимает обычный массив из строк, а результат возвращает в виде Json.

Сначала создаем модель ответа сервера(поля объявлены как `public` с целью уменьшения кода, в реальном приложении лучше использовать `private` + get/set методы):

```
public class AddEmailResult {
    @SerializedName("email")
    public String email;
    @SerializedName("primary")
    public Boolean primary;
    @SerializedName("verified")
    public Boolean verified;
}
```

Теперь создаем интерфейс, через который будет происходить взаимодействие с сервером.

```
public interface Server {
    @POST("user/addemail") 
    Call<List<AddEmailResult>> addEmail(@Body List<String> emails)
}
```

Аннотация над методом означает что будет выполнен `POST` запрос, аннотация `@Body` указывает на то, что этот объект должен быть передан в теле запроса.

Далее необходимо создать сервера. Делается это так:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com") // Адрес сервера
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // говорим ретрофиту что для сериализации необходимо использовать GSON
    .build();

Server service = retrofit.create(Server.class);
Call<List<AddEmailResult>> call = service.addEmail(/*list of string*/)
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<AddEmailResult>>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<AddEmailResult>> call, Response<List<AddEmailResult>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // запрос выполнился успешно, сервер вернул Status 200
        } else {
            // сервер вернул ошибку
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<AddEmailResult>> call, Throwable t) {
        // ошибка во время выполнения запроса
    }
});
```

Вызывая метод `enqueue()` вы говорите что бы запрос выполнился асинхронно. В конце результат придет в переданный callback где его можно обработать.
Вот в принципе и все. Данная библиотека не ограничивается одним лишь `POST` запросом, она умеет делать все, что нужно для разработки клиент-серверного приложения.

Что бы добавить retrofit к себе в проект, необходимо в `build.gradle` добавить следующее:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, немного разобрался, но возник очередной вопрос, как получить ответ синхронно через `execute`? Я хочу чтобы приложение при запуске делало проверку данных через `API` и в зависимости от ответа выполняла действие, но я не могу при запуске синхронно получить данные с `API` и приложение выполняет всегда действие когда ответ от `API` == `null`

Comment: @tCode метод execute работает синхронно, но стоит учитывать что Android не допускает работы с сетью в главном потоке. В вашем случае вы скорей всего пытаетесь работать с ответом сразу после метода enqueue, но в этот момент запрос ещё не завершился. Вам нужно обрабатывать ответ в колбеке, который передаете в мнтод enqueue

Comment: @termq, спасибо, получилось)

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё один пример с готовой активностью, отправляющий на сервер простой json. Скопировал из своего ответа:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new RequestTask().execute("http://www.site.ru/login.php"); // скрипт, на который посылаем запрос
}

public String getJSON(String login, String pass) // получаем json объект в виде строки
{
    JSONObject bot = new JSONObject();
    try {
        bot.put("Login", login);
        bot.put("Password", pass);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bot.toString();
}

public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // ключ - "json", параметр - json в виде строки
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", getJSON("userlogin", "userpass")));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8");
            postMethod.setEntity(entity);
            return hc.execute(postMethod, res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        // res - ответ сервера

        super.onPostExecute(res);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Ожидание");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
}
```

Обработать запрос можно, например, на PHP:

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['json']; // получаем json объект
$array = json_decode($json, true); // преобразуем его в ассоциативный массив
// получаем из него данные
$login = $array['Login'];
$pass = $array['Password'];
// дальше уже делаем то, что нужно
file_put_contents('login.txt', "$login\n$pass");
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, в ответ от сервиса можно замаппить на класс?

Answer (score 2):

> AsyncTask лучше один раз попробовать, и потом забыть про них. То же
>   самое касается и HttpUrlConnection. В настоящий момент основной
>   библиотекой для взаимодействия с Rest сервером в Android считается
>   Retorofti.

Имхо, Retrofit тяжелая, при этом не лучшим образом документированная библиотека, ориентированная на работу с web порталами со своими API. По крайней мере, все примеры в сети иллюстрируют работу именно с ними.
Ели-же вам нужно по http передать строку в 10 символов, не создавая при этом кучу ненужного в последствии кода, HttpUrlConnection + AsyncTask подойдет как нельзя лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простой пример отправки запроса. params это просто неограниченный массив стрингов. HttpPost принимает строку которая является адресом скрипта на сервере.
BasicNameValuePair - это просто список ключ значение того, что вы отправляете. response это то что вывел нам серверный скрипт. Совсем не обязательно делать это в AsyncTask. Но обычно делают в нем. Т.к это не моментальная операция и лучше бы ее обрабатывать в новом потоке. Если нужно что-то конкретно пояснить, напишите в комментариях. Я отвечу

```
String doInBackground(String... params) throws IOException {
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID_group", PageViewActivity.Get_list_group.get(PageViewActivity.Cur_group_position).get(0)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID_group", group_id));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login", Login));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", Password));
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            String response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
            System.out.println(response);
            return response;
        }
```

А теперь о парсинге json. response - строка с json

```
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("Resourse");
            for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject actor = null;
                actor = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                String Text = null;
                Text = actor.getString("ID");
                News_list.add(text);
           }
```

Пример самого json который мы парсим можно тут увидеть. Чисто для понимания формата http://contester.ddns.is74.ru:84/Get_all_group_list.ashx

Comment: у вас передаются конкретные стринговые параметры `ID_group`, `Login` и т.д., а можно это как универсализировать?

Comment: @tCode это просто пример. Можно любые пары стринг значений. Воспринимайте это как мар который мы отправляем на сервер. Где потом скрипт на сервере должен по ключу достать значение.