# Android отправка Json на сервер PHP

Tags: php, android, json

Пожалуйста, помогите столкнулся с проблемой, мне надо передать Post запрос в формате Json  на сервер  PHP
"data":[{"loginwrk":"***","dname":"***"}]}, принять на стороне php и присвоить значение переменным, &loginwrk и &Json   подходящего решения для себя не нашел, много примеров с apache библиотекой, которая уже не поддерживается, буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Вы таки определитесь, с чем у Вас проблема. С точки зрения разработки под андроид нет никакой разницы, на php сервер или на чем другом. Также и серверу глубоко все равно, шлет запросы андроид или что-то другое. У Вас проблема принять POST запрос на сервере? Это один вопрос. У Вас проблема отправить POST запрос из андроида? Это совсем другой вопрос. Друг с другом эти два вопроса никак не связаны. Не мешало бы указать, на чем Вы пишете под андроид (java/kotlin/jsNative/flatter и т д) и php(например, yii2 или что-то другое)

Comment: Не понимаю как принять post запрос на стороне сервера php, читать без проблем, через HttpUrlConnection, с отправкой затруднение. Для меня тут подходящий предпоследний пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625649/post-запросы-в-android-Как , но увы он на устаревшей библиотека написан, подобный пример не могу найти.

Comment: Я Вам настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с retrofit

Comment: "как принять post запрос на стороне сервера php, с отправкой затруднение". Дружище, давай без паники и сбивчивых фраз. Проблемы с отправкой или принятием? И точно ли нужен именно JSON? Правильно заданный вопрос содержит в себе половину ответа.

Comment: Ну можно и не json, мне нужно передать эти 2 параметра в процедуру mysql, для авторизации в приложении. Проблема с самой отправкой, не понимаю как его отправить с клиента android и обработать на стороне сервера php.

Comment: CALL uPersData4Auth('$loginwrk', '$dname'), у меня есть процедура с 2 входными параметрами, это логин и пароль, меня интересует как post запросом отправить эти 2 параметра, с получением ответа проблем не возникло.